# Append data to an existing file in new line cocoa

Tags: cocoa, file

I'm developing a Cocoa application for Mac. I have to append data of a file to an existing file in new line. I am trying to do this by following code:

```
NSData * theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"~/Desktop/test/new.rtf"
                                          options: NSMappedRead
                                            error: &error];
NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"~/Desktop/test/test.rtf"];
[output seekToEndOfFile];
[output writeData:theData];
```

But this code is not working. This code is doing nothing. Neither giving any error nor writing data of file new.rtf to test.rtf. Any idea how can I append data of file new.rtf to test.rtf in new line??

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *readFile = [@"~/Desktop/test/new.rtf" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSString *writeFile = [@"~/Desktop/test/test.rtf" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

NSData * theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:readFile
                                          options:NSMappedRead
                                            error:NULL];

NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:writeFile];
[output seekToEndOfFile];
[output writeData:theData];
[output closeFile];
```

Comment: What if you close the file handle, using `[output closeFile];`?

Comment: Nothing happening even after closing the file handle.

Comment: Does the log statement I suggested print out the data object, or does it just print "(null)"?

Comment: The log statement NSLog(@"thd Data: %@", theData); is printing the data object. I used same theData to write a new file using theData writeToFile function and new file is created with data of existing file.

Comment: Okay, you have to do `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` and you also have to create the file before writing to it with `NSFileHandle`. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Its creating new file and writing data in that due to that existing data of file is deleted. But I have to append data to the existing file in new line without deleting data of existing file.

Comment: What if you try using the `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` method instead? (See updated answer.)

Comment: Not working for     fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: method. No any output.